# Starting Tomcat6 on Debian as non-root user

Tags: tomcat, debian, tomcat6

I'm trying to start tomcat6 on Debian (installed via aptitude) as non-root user. 
But startup-script tells me, that I need to be root to start.

Anybody who changed the script, so that a normal user is able to start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of modifying the script you might consider to add the non-root user to the sudoer list.

To do so, login as root and add following line at the end of the file `/etc/sudoers` (either use your editor of choice or simply type `visudo` in the command line):

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) /etc/init.d/tomcat6
```

Then you can start/stop/restart tomcat with sudo, e.g.:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

If you are tired of having to enter the password all the time, modify your entry in `/etc/sudoers` this way:

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/tomcat6
```

Comment: What if I need to remotly run this script with ssh? Like  ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop